# Unable to fetch Cookies after succesfully login using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login in a Site and trying to fetch the cookies. I already successfully login to the site but I am not able to fetch the Cookies of the page after successful login.

**Here's my code**

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Webdriver_class{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("URL from where I login");

        WebElement id= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[15]/div[2]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/input"));
        WebElement pass=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[15]/div[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/input"));
        WebElement button=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[15]/div[2]/form/div[2]/button[1]"));

        id.sendKeys("my username");
        pass.sendKeys("my password");
        button.click();


        Set<Cookie> testCookie = driver.manage().getCookies();

        Iterator<Cookie> iter= testCookie.iterator();

        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Cookie C = iter.next();
            System.out.println(C.getName()+"-------------------" + C.getPath()+"--------------------"+ C.getDomain()+"----"+C.getValue()+"---"+C.getExpiry());

        }
    }

}
```

It return no cookies. On printing the driver.manage().getCookies(); I am getting

```
[]
```

Comment: If cookies are HttpOnly you cannot retrieve them from Selenium webdriver.